# Run logstash forwarder and web as a daemon on ubuntu

Tags: daemon, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am currently using logstash-1.4.2. In which you don't get the standard monolithic or flat jar which used to be the case earlier. Now, i want to start the logstash forwarder as a service.

```
bin/logstash -f logforwareder.conf
```

Above command runs it in the foreground. So it gets killed everytime i close/exit the terminal.

Similarly, for the LogStash indexer how do i achieve the same.

```
  bin/logstash -f indexer.conf web
```

This command also kills indexer once terminal is closed.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Then just install the Debian package from http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/download/. Logstash will be set up to start at boot and you can start or stop it anytime with the `start` and `stop` commands.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, don't forget to have your own configuration file at */etc/logstash-forwarder* (without .conf).

```
{
  "network":
  {
     "servers": [
       "logstash.server.ip:5000"
     ],
     "ssl ca":
       "/etc/ssl/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
     "timeout": 15
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         "/var/log/apache2/access_web1.log",
         "/var/log/apache2/access_web2.log"
      ],
      "fields": {
         "type": "apache",
         "environment": "production"
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

You can check the script to see where is it looking for the config file:

```
vi /etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder
```